# Rendering floated elements occasionally pushes them below nav bar

Tags: html, css-float

I'm not entirely sure what is happening here, but occasionally some floated elements move beyond the navigation bar. Since it happens inconsistently, I thought it might be a browser rendering issue - refreshing the page a few times usually makes it go away.  Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Live link [here](http://joevial.me/wip/index.html). Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `.nav-list` class needs more width. I tried this and it looks better:

```
.nav-list {
    float: right;
    width: 340px;
}
```

styles.css (line 307)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Initially I hadn't specified a width and just put it at 320px before this question, but was still having issues maybe I should have gone a little wider. I just pushed 340px up. I'm still having issues in Chrome, but I suspect its just a cacheing issue now.

Comment: It looks like the issue is persisting on Chrome, have a feeling it may not be a cacheing issue, but a render issue still.

Comment: It looks good to me on Chrome. http://d.pr/i/NQKX Can you post a screenshot? Did you clear your Chrome cache?

Comment: Yes, I just emptied it and I'm still seeing the issue, and another set of eyes confirmed it today. :\

Perhaps it was okay for you this time? It seems persistently intermittent in Chrome, but fine in Safari and Firefox from what I can see.